# python executables alarms antivirus

Tags: python, pyinstaller, antivirus

I made a simple GUI (wxpython) application (some static text, buttons, comboboxes etc) and made exe file with pyinstaller, but the Avast antivirus says it's a virus. How can I fix this?

Comment: Uninstall Avast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program made with PyInstaller now seen as a Trojan Horse by AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg)

Answer (score 4):

Send your EXE file to [Avast](http://www.avast.com/contacts) for analysis:

> Report a Virus
>
> If you’ve encountered a suspicious file or received what you think is
>   a *false-positive virus alert*, please [contact our Virus Lab](http://www.avast.com/contact-us.php?subject=VIRUS-FILE) for an
>   analysis.

There is also a [bug report](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/603) for PyInstaller about this. The bug was supposedly fixed 13 months ago. Perhaps you should reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
If you are using Avast, do not uninstall it.
This will make your computer vulnerable from threats.
If you are sure, you can click 'add exclusion' when the Avast Hardened Mode blocked a program thing comes up.
If this isn't correct, please comment or edit.