# When I download my .exe file on another PC I get the message: Windows protected your PC. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, download, pyinstaller, exe

I made a program in Python, and exported it to .exe using pyinstaller in one file. I have published it on my webpage in a .zip container (I have tried publishing it bare too.).

When I download it, unpack it, and run it I get the pop-up: "Windows protected your PC. Microsoft Defender SmartScreen blocked an unknown app to start. Running this app kan put your PC at risk" (Translated from norwegian, so maybe not 100% correct to the word.)

Here is the link to the download: https://gerhardadler.no/tetris/ (It is in norwegian, but the only button on the page starts the download.)(This page will be changed or removed in the future.)

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller .exe throws Windows Defender \[no publisher\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377666/pyinstaller-exe-throws-windows-defender-no-publisher)

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, thank you. Very unfortunate that you have to pay for a certificate. :/