# Py2Exe detected as virus. Alternatives?

Tags: windows, computer-science, py2exe, malware, virus

So, I created a python program. Converted to exe using Py2Exe, and tried with PyInstaller and cx_freeze as well. All these trigger the program to be detected as virus by avast, avg, and others on virustotal and on my local machine.

I tried changing to a Hello World script to see if the problem is there but the results are exactly the same.

My question is, what is triggering this detection? The way in which the .exe is created?

If so, are there any other alternatives to Py2exe, Pyinstaller, cx_freeze?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program made with PyInstaller now seen as a Trojan Horse by AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg)

Answer (score 2):

You can try nuitka.

```
pip install -U nuitka
```

Example:

```
nuitka --recurse-all --icon=app.ico --portable helloworld.py
```

Website:

http://nuitka.net/

Maybe you need to install Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools for compile.

http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Answer (score 0):

If you download Nuitka package, you will find a Trojan files in the folder.

If you use this library, you will create a exe file with a Trojan embedded in the exe file.

It converts files much faster than other similar libraries with no errors.

Comment: To clarify: you're recommending Nuitka because you believe it contains a virus? (I don't think it does - I think it's reputable). I'm not sure it actually *reliably* solves the problem of false positives from virus scanners though