# Best way to build exe from python code to avoid AV false positive

Tags: python, pyinstaller, antivirus

I Have developed a application using python 3.6 and have built it as a exe using pyIntaller. The exe is blocked by many well know Anti Viruses as a trojan/virus. Form the past 2 days of research, I have figured out there is no way to resolve this problem. However are there any known best practices to be followed whcih can reduce the probability of the exe being blocked by AV. I know the best solution is to sent the exe to all the AV vendors and get it excluded, but this is not really help in my case, due to time factors and the release mechanism. So looking out for any support here. My application is build using the following python modules:

```
altgraph (0.15)
macholib (1.9)
matplotlib (2.1.2)
numpy (1.14.0)
pandas (0.22.0)
pefile (2017.11.5)
pyinstall (0.1.4)
PyInstaller (3.3.1)
pyparsing (2.2.0)
pypiwin32 (220)
PySide 
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2018.3)
sip (4.19.7)
six (1.11.0)
XlsxWriter (1.0.2)
```

Comment: Related: [Program made with PyInstaller now seen as a Trojan Horse by AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43777106/3357935)

Comment: Check [how-to-recompile-the-bootloader-of-pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584395/how-to-recompile-the-bootloader-of-pyinstaller). it's not difficult to rebuild the `bootloader`, and `pyinstaller` has more external libraries support than `py2exe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to py2exe module in python.

Answer (score -2):

OK can you tried Base64 enc
just go to https://www.base64encode.net/ encrypt your python code
than import base64
here the codes:
import base64

exec(base64.standard_b64decode("BASE64 CODE"))

Comment: 1. Base64 encoding isn't encryption. 2. Using `exec` in any serious application without knowing all the potential pitfalls is bad, _bad_, **bad** advice.