# PyInstaller Pre-Compiled Bootloader Not Found and Build Fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, pyinstaller

I have:
Windows 10, 64-bit
Python 3.8.1
tkinter 8.6.9
PyInstaller 3.6

When I try to create an exe from a .py script using a -w flag, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: PyInstaller does not include a pre-compiled bootloader for your platform.
```

I do not get the error with PyInstaller without the -w flag, but I don't want a console to appear when it is run.

Also, my PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit directory has bootloaders run.exe, run_d.exe, runw.exe, and runw_d.exe and Windows-32bit directory has run.exe, run_d.exe, and runw_d.exe - so the precompiled boot loaders do appear to be there unless 32-bit runw.exe is the one I need for -w.

I was following the instructions here: [how to recompile the bootloader of Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584395/how-to-recompile-the-bootloader-of-pyinstaller)

I downloaded the .tar.gz file for PyInstaller, and went to the bootloader directory and ran the command `python ./waf distclean all`

Then I got the error:

```
Build failed  
-> task in 'run_d' failed with exit status 1 (run with
-v to display more information)
```

Here's most of my config.log file (I deleted options information to make it fit):

```
# project PyInstallerBootloader (nodist) configured on Fri Jan 31 13:44:31 2020 by
# waf 2.0.19 (abi 20, python 30801f0 on win32)
# using ./waf distclean all
#
---------------------------------------- Setting top to M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader
---------------------------------------- Setting out to \\server1\HOME\usera\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\build
---------------------------------------- Python Version
3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
---------------------------------------- Checking for 'msvc' (C compiler) ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\vswhere.exe', '-products', '*', '-legacy', '-format', 'json'] ['cmd.exe', '/E:on', '/V:on', '/C', '\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\waf-print-msvc-1.bat'] out: PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\VC\BIN\amd64;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86;C:\ActiveTcl\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Vector vFlash 4\Bin\Automation\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Vector vFlash
2.7\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2017b\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015b\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Plantronics\Spokes3G\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Pico Technology\PicoScope6\;C:\Users\usera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\usera\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\;C:\Users\usera\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;c:\ActiveTcl\bin

INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt;

LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral;\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral;


find program=['CL'] paths=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x86', 'C:\\ActiveTcl\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 4\\Bin\\Automation\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 2.7\\Bin\\', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plantronics\\Spokes3G\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pico Technology\\PicoScope6\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'c:\\ActiveTcl\\bin'] var='CL' -> ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe'] ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/help'] out:


find program=['LINK'] paths=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x86', 'C:\\ActiveTcl\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 4\\Bin\\Automation\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 2.7\\Bin\\', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plantronics\\Spokes3G\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pico Technology\\PicoScope6\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'c:\\ActiveTcl\\bin'] var='LINK_CXX' -> ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\LINK.exe'] find program=['LIB'] paths=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x86', 'C:\\ActiveTcl\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 4\\Bin\\Automation\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 2.7\\Bin\\', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plantronics\\Spokes3G\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pico Technology\\PicoScope6\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'c:\\ActiveTcl\\bin'] var='AR' -> ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\LIB.exe'] find program=['MT'] paths=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x86', 'C:\\ActiveTcl\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 4\\Bin\\Automation\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 2.7\\Bin\\', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plantronics\\Spokes3G\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pico Technology\\PicoScope6\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'c:\\ActiveTcl\\bin'] var='MT' -> ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64\\MT.exe'] find program=['RC'] paths=['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\bin\\amd64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x86', 'C:\\ActiveTcl\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 4\\Bin\\Automation\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vector vFlash 2.7\\Bin\\', 'C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32', 'C:\\WINDOWS', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2017b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\runtime\\win64', 'C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2015b\\bin', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plantronics\\Spokes3G\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Pico Technology\\PicoScope6\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\Scripts\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\', 'C:\\Users\\usera\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'c:\\ActiveTcl\\bin'] var='WINRC' -> ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64\\RC.exe'] C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\amd64\CL.exe
---------------------------------------- Checking size of pointer
==>

        int main() {
            static int test_array[1 - 2 * !(sizeof(void *) == 4)];
            test_array[0] = 0;
            return 0;
        } <== [1/2] Compiling [32m\\server1\HOME\usera\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\build\conf_check_303e219cf805e8bf7cae31152a34da6b\test.c[0m

['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '..\\test.c', '/FC', '/c', '/Fo\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_303e219cf805e8bf7cae31152a34da6b\\testbuild\\test.c.1.o'] out: test.c

\\server1\HOME\usera\my documents\python\pyinstaller\bootloader\build\conf_check_303e219cf805e8bf7cae31152a34da6b\test.c(3): error C2118: negative subscript


from M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\waf3-2.0.19-9054d7a7f551c4b14b458abcd389b706\waflib\Configure.py", line 333, in run_build
    bld.compile()   File "M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\waf3-2.0.19-9054d7a7f551c4b14b458abcd389b706\waflib\Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error) waflib.Errors.BuildError: Build failed  -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 2 (run with -v to display more information)

from M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader: The configuration failed
==>

        int main() {
            static int test_array[1 - 2 * !(sizeof(void *) == 8)];
            test_array[0] = 0;
            return 0;
        } <== [1/2] Compiling [32m\\server1\HOME\usera\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\build\conf_check_df399ceca844fdee226fb77c6f4a4073\test.c[0m

['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '..\\test.c', '/FC', '/c', '/Fo\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_df399ceca844fdee226fb77c6f4a4073\\testbuild\\test.c.1.o'] out: test.c


[2/2] Linking [33m\\server1\HOME\usera\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\build\conf_check_df399ceca844fdee226fb77c6f4a4073\testbuild\testprog.exe[0m

['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\LINK.exe', '/nologo', '/MANIFEST', 'test.c.1.o', '/OUT:\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_df399ceca844fdee226fb77c6f4a4073\\testbuild\\testprog.exe', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\LIB\\amd64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\lib\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt\\x64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\lib\\winv6.3\\um\\x64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\LIB\\amd64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319', '/LIBPATH:C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\References\\CommonConfiguration\\Neutral', '/LIBPATH:\\Microsoft.VCLibs\\14.0\\References\\CommonConfiguration\\neutral'] ['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\bin\\x64\\MT.exe', '/nologo', '-manifest', '\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_df399ceca844fdee226fb77c6f4a4073\\testbuild\\testprog.exe.manifest', '-outputresource:\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_df399ceca844fdee226fb77c6f4a4073\\testbuild\\testprog.exe;1'] 8
---------------------------------------- Platform Windows-64bit detected based on compiler
---------------------------------------- Checking for function unsetenv
==>

    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        void (*p)();

        (void)argc; (void)argv;
        p=(void(*)())(unsetenv);
        return !p;
    }

<== [1/2] Compiling [32m\\server1\HOME\usera\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\build\conf_check_2b863466c990906d29ccc349c383bbe8\test.cpp[0m

['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '/DWIN32', '..\\test.cpp', '/FC', '/c', '/Fo\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_2b863466c990906d29ccc349c383bbe8\\testbuild\\test.cpp.1.o'] out: test.cpp

\\server1\HOME\usera\my documents\python\pyinstaller\bootloader\build\conf_check_2b863466c990906d29ccc349c383bbe8\test.cpp(8): error C2065: 'unsetenv': undeclared identifier


from M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\waf3-2.0.19-9054d7a7f551c4b14b458abcd389b706\waflib\Configure.py", line 333, in run_build
    bld.compile()   File "M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\waf3-2.0.19-9054d7a7f551c4b14b458abcd389b706\waflib\Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error) waflib.Errors.BuildError: Build failed  -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 2 (run with -v to display more information)

no from M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader: The configuration failed
---------------------------------------- Checking for function mkdtemp
==>

    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        void (*p)();

        (void)argc; (void)argv;
        p=(void(*)())(mkdtemp);
        return !p;
    }

<== [1/2] Compiling [32m\\server1\HOME\usera\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\build\conf_check_35bda8a5d479c0fc31bb3ca93a5c8147\test.cpp[0m

['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '/DWIN32', '..\\test.cpp', '/FC', '/c', '/Fo\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_35bda8a5d479c0fc31bb3ca93a5c8147\\testbuild\\test.cpp.1.o'] out: test.cpp

\\server1\HOME\usera\my documents\python\pyinstaller\bootloader\build\conf_check_35bda8a5d479c0fc31bb3ca93a5c8147\test.cpp(8): error C2065: 'mkdtemp': undeclared identifier


from M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\waf3-2.0.19-9054d7a7f551c4b14b458abcd389b706\waflib\Configure.py", line 333, in run_build
    bld.compile()   File "M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\waf3-2.0.19-9054d7a7f551c4b14b458abcd389b706\waflib\Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error) waflib.Errors.BuildError: Build failed  -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 2 (run with -v to display more information)

no from M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader: The configuration failed
---------------------------------------- Checking for function strndup
==>

    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        void (*p)();

        (void)argc; (void)argv;
        p=(void(*)())(strndup);
        return !p;
    }

<== [1/2] Compiling [32m\\server1\HOME\usera\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\build\conf_check_0dd60a7756386d5da02cc6ba31c28717\test.cpp[0m

['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '/DWIN32', '..\\test.cpp', '/FC', '/c', '/Fo\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_0dd60a7756386d5da02cc6ba31c28717\\testbuild\\test.cpp.1.o'] out: test.cpp

\\server1\HOME\usera\my documents\python\pyinstaller\bootloader\build\conf_check_0dd60a7756386d5da02cc6ba31c28717\test.cpp(8): error C2065: 'strndup': undeclared identifier


from M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader: Test does not build: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\waf3-2.0.19-9054d7a7f551c4b14b458abcd389b706\waflib\Configure.py", line 333, in run_build
    bld.compile()   File "M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\waf3-2.0.19-9054d7a7f551c4b14b458abcd389b706\waflib\Build.py", line 176, in compile
    raise Errors.BuildError(self.producer.error) waflib.Errors.BuildError: Build failed  -> task in 'testprog' failed with exit status 2 (run with -v to display more information)

no from M:\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader: The configuration failed
---------------------------------------- Checking for function strnlen
==>

    #include <string.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        void (*p)();

        (void)argc; (void)argv;
        p=(void(*)())(strnlen);
        return !p;
    }

<== [1/2] Compiling [32m\\server1\HOME\usera\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\build\conf_check_21240939c9ddbcc20d9e6d66cf882183\test.cpp[0m

['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\CL.exe', '/nologo', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\INCLUDE', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\include\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\shared', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\um', '/IC:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\include\\winrt', '/DWIN32', '..\\test.cpp', '/FC', '/c', '/Fo\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_21240939c9ddbcc20d9e6d66cf882183\\testbuild\\test.cpp.1.o'] out: test.cpp


[2/2] Linking [33m\\server1\HOME\usera\My Documents\Python\PyInstaller\Bootloader\build\conf_check_21240939c9ddbcc20d9e6d66cf882183\testbuild\testprog.exe[0m

['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\amd64\\LINK.exe', '/nologo', '/MANIFEST', '/MACHINE:X64', 'test.cpp.1.o', '/OUT:\\\\server1\\HOME\\usera\\My Documents\\Python\\PyInstaller\\Bootloader\\build\\conf_check_21240939c9ddbcc20d9e6d66cf882183\\testbuild\\testprog.exe', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\LIB\\amd64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\lib\\10.0.10240.0\\ucrt\\x64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\lib\\winv6.3\\um\\x64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\\VC\\LIB\\amd64', '/LIBPATH:C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\v4.0.30319', '/LIBPATH:C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework64\\', '/LIBPATH:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.1\\References\\CommonConfiguration\\Neutral', '/LIBPATH:\\Microsoft.VCLibs\\14.0\\References\\CommonConfiguration\\neutral'] yes
```

What am I possibly missing that I can't do the build?

Comment: Do you have anti-virus software running? Some mentions of that on GitHub for a [very similar issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4318).

Comment: Yes, that looks like it's my problem. I manually found runw.exe and tried copying it, and as soon as I copy it over - poof, it's gone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be caused by anti-virus software.  See this PyInstaller [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4318) for more details:

> Okay, I think I might have identified the problem, and it's
>   anti-virus.
>
> Since the files were missing, I tried copying them from a downloaded
>   tarball of PyInstaller 3.5. After placing them in the appropriate
>   folder, all but runw_d.exe were shortly thereafter quarantined (albeit
>   not removed as they appear to have been during pip installation).
>
> I've seen other references to anti-virus causing issues with these
>   files, so I'll take this up with my IT group.

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4318#issuecomment-518281240

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're missing the runw.exe in the folder Windows-32bit.

This is how I solved this:

- open your command prompt and cd to your site-packages folder (if you're working in a venv first activate that!).
- run the command: 'git clone [https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git'](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git%27) inside your site-packages folder.

Btw I'm using python 3.7.0 32bit on a 64bit windows.

That should work! Hoped this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind at the moment python 3.8 is not officially supported by pyinstaller.

[Add support for Python 3.8 · Issue #4311 · pyinstaller/pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4311)

Maybe sing python 3.7 might help you?