# Problem with compiler for bootloader of Pyinstaller

Tags: python, c++, pyinstaller, virus

easy question here (I hope), I am a noob about this topic.

I am facing problem of "virus" with the ".exe" file generated by pyinstaller.
I read that a new bootloader of pyinstaller could help.

So following these links:

[how to recompile the bootloader of Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584395/how-to-recompile-the-bootloader-of-pyinstaller)

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bootloader-building.html#id9

and I stop at this point:

[image: Output for the main step of procedure]

So I installed this package:

Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable per Visual Studio 2019 - VC_redist.x56.exe

But it did not work. I have no idea how to teach python /system to find the Compiler.

I tried to install the TDM-GCC compiler, I run it and I got:

[image: TDM-GCC compiler test]

I have no other idea.

Please help

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed this version of Visual Studio package:

[image: The magic Visual Studio package (sorry for Italian)]

and the g++ compiler has been installed correctly.

I followed the procedure written here:

[how to recompile the bootloader of Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584395/how-to-recompile-the-bootloader-of-pyinstaller)

and I obtain a perfect version of pyinstaller with no virus checked with virustotal.com