# pyinstaller created EXE which windows detect as a virus

Tags: exe, pyinstaller

I have a simple selenium python script as EXE(by pyinstaller).
I uploaded it to a sharing website and every time I download it(to my computer or other computers), windows detect it as a VIRUS when tried to open. sometimes chrome won't download it, saying "virus detected". But there is nothing harmful about it, What's the problem? Have something to do with the RAR compress?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program made with PyInstaller now seen as a Trojan Horse by AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg)

Comment: @ftv not excatly because windows defender suggests its a VIRUS not AVG

Comment: How many hits do you get with https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload  ?