# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: pyinstaller.exe/TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, permissions, pyinstaller

I am trying to execute TKinter .py file into .exe file with the following command:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile Weather_App.py
```

In the command prompt, I receive the following error:

**PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Python Scripts\TKinter_Projects\Weather_App.spec'**

[this is the link to a screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/J1vDe5p.png)

Please could anyone help? I tried everything I could.
(Please let me know if I need to upload more info, this is my first question).

Thanks all.

Comment: Try executing pyinstaller.exe with Admin / Superuser permissions

Comment: Is the .spec file created at that location?, if so run the spec file. This may be an overzealous antivirus holding the file open immediately after it's creation while pyinstaller is trying to access it, or the file isn't where pyinstaller thinks it is.

Comment: tgikal, you are absolutely right, the antivirus was a problem! I didn't work out how to run .spec file, but I temporary disabled 'safe files' option in my antivirus and it worked :) Thank you

Comment: how do I vote for a comment to be the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

When I create an exe file using pyinstaller then antivirus removing the exe file instantly.

but finally, pyinstaller worked for me after following these ways.

- `python -m PyInstaller file.spec`
- or if the issue persists follow this link
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52054580/10537606

hope it works for you

Answer (score -2):

Did you try running command prompt as an administrator? That may be why your permission is denied.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it - didn't change a thing unfortunately