# Exe Download Failure

Tags: python, windows, google-chrome, exe, pyinstaller

I recently constructed a program in Python 3.0. This program requires quite a few modules and I intend to share this with my friends. However it would surely be inconvenient for them to install the python IDE (as they mostly are not programmers) and then pip install the other modules. So therefore I used pyinstaller to turn the py file into a exe file. This way all of my friends could just run the file and run it without having to install other software and modules. I saved this file on Sync, and I emailed a link to my friends . However when they tried to download it on chrome, it said :

‘Download Failed - Virus Detected’

It says this and cancels the download.

I made this program and I am absolutely certain that there is no virus on it. Am I doing something wrong or have I missed a step??

Thanks

Comment: You could sign the .exe file

Comment: @JCWasmx86 How should I sign the exe file

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this should not happen, your program is most likely no virus.

Unfortunately this is a known issue with pyinstaller.

Take a look at [Program made with PyInstaller now seen as a Trojan Horse by AVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777106/program-made-with-pyinstaller-now-seen-as-a-trojan-horse-by-avg)

There are some solutions, maybe one of them works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I haven't tried this yet but I will soon. The most convenient way is looking like downgrading PyInstaller to 3.4 from my current version of 3.6. I have not tested it against AVG yet, what do you recommend? Downgrading or testing with AVG?

Comment: Furthermore, are you sure this is an error with pyinstaller? Couldn't it possible be an error with Chrome or the Windows Defender

Comment: I would try downgrading...Regarding the error: It's the problem of both, pyinstaller and Chrome. Pyinstaller builds sth that looks like a virus and Chrome detects a false positive. The solution I would look for is to build a executable out of a python script that does not look like a virus.